# MySQL - Grant access permissions does not work

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to give access permissions to a user for specific database in mysql. But the command does not seem to take effect.

Here's what I mean:

step 1:

- create db 'testdb'
- grant permissions to 'dummyuser'@'%' on testbd.*
- try to access mysql with testdb user (FAILS)

root@bnode1 /]# mysql -h 172.22.191.202 -u root -ppassword

```
MariaDB [(none)]> 
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testdb;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> grant all privileges on testdb.* to 'dummyuser'@'%'   identified by 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> exit
Bye
[root@bnode1 /]# 
[root@bnode1 /]# mysql -h 172.22.191.202 -u dummyuser -ppassword
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dummyuser'@'bnode1' (using   password: YES)
```

On the mysql database I can see the grant priviliges for dummyuser as below:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for 'dummyuser';
+-----------------------------------------+
| Grants for dummyuser@%                                                                                        |
+-----------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'dummyuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD     '*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testdb`.* TO 'dummyuser'@'%'                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Step 2:
Now I tried another thing. grant permisson to user 'dummyuser'@'bnode1', 
same commands, and with that now I am able to access.

```
root@bnode1 /]# mysql -h 172.22.191.202 -u root -ppassword     
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
...

MariaDB [(none)]> grant all privileges on testdb.* to '**dummyuser'@'bnode1'** identified by 'passwor>
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> exit
Bye
[root@bnode1 /]# 
[root@bnode1 /]# 
[root@bnode1 /]# mysql -h 172.22.191.202 -u dummyuser -ppassword
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
...
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

I am not an expert in mysql, can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is visually inspect the User table in `mysql` tablespace, and verify the host is indeed '%' (and not, who knows, '\'%\''). As far as I can tell you did everything right. It *should* have worked.

Comment: couldn't find the table which specifies this. Can you give me more details how I can figure out whether the host is '%' or something else.

Comment: I remember experienced problem with the `%` operator. I fixed it specifying the host to connect, maybe you could try it.

Comment: The table is mysql.user ( https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysqluser-table/ ); so you could try `USE mysql; SELECT Host, User from user where User IN ('dummyuser', 'root');` and see if you spot any difference.

Comment: Do you have another user entry (possibly anonymous) that matches the incoming connection more exactly than `'dummyuser'@'%'`?  If so, that entry will take precedence.  See [Access Control, Stage 1: Connection Verification](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/connection-access.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dummyuser'@'bnode1' (using   password: YES)

You may need to try to connect from the other host to see if 'bnode1' is restricted for 'dummyuser'

Or you can create a fresh user(as you didn't show the create user command I assume it's an existing user) and the grant command you did should work.

Not likely but just in case, you need ensure 'bind=0.0.0.0' in my.cnf.